# Связаны ли BOOTAPP из команды bcdedit /create /? в описании параметра /application и подсистемы Boot в линкере Microsoft?

Tags: c++, windows, osdev

Я когда-то смотрел команду link с параметром /? и увидел подсистему BOOT, которой нет в visual studio. Я пошёл искать информацию про подсистему, но не нашёл. Недавно я выполнилнил команду bcdedit /create /? и увидел, что в описании параметра /application  указано, что  может быть BOOTAPP. Информации в интернете я не нашёл. Связана ли подсистема BOOT с загрузчиком Windows, как создать приложение для загрузчика Windows на C++ и можно ли использовать это для osdev?

Comment: Может эта статья [Загрузка и UEFI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/bringup/boot-and-uefi) поможет в поиске ответов?